# Regex, match values inside of curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

Having the next string

`{ Hello, testing, hi stack overflow, how is it going }`

Match every word inside of curly brackets without the comma.

I tried this:

`\{(.*)\}` which take all, commas and brackets included.

`\{\w+\}` I thought this will work for words but it wont, why?

### Updated

Tried this but I got null, why?

```
    str = "{ Hello, testing, hi stack overflow, how is it going }";
    str2 = str.match("\{(.*?)\}")[1]; // Taking the second group
    console.log(str2);
    console.log(str2.match("/w+"));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try:

first get everything between {} by using

```
\{(.*?)\}
```

then get all words inside of the resulting string.

```
\w+
```

Here is an explanation:

```
\w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
```

Comment: it gets all words but not only those ones who are inside of curly brackets

Comment: I think that you're so right also it makes sense but for some reason I got null, pretty sure that it's me doing the things wrong, so I'm gonna update the post with the code!

Comment: Nevermind, I just realize I was doing `/w+` instead of `\w+`, thanks!